# How to get informations on each type of filesystem in /proc/filesystems

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, proc

How do we get detailed information (history, what is used for, etc.) on each filesystem or pseudo filesystem displayed by :

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```

Example : **nodev**, **sysfs**, **rootfs**, **ramfs**, **bdev**, **proc** , **cgroup**, **cpuset**, **tmpfs**, **devtmpsfs**, **debugfs**, **securityfs**, **sockfs**, **dax**, **pipefs**, **anon_inodefs**, **configfs**, **devpts**, **hungelbfs**, **autofs**, **pstore**, **mqueue**, **selinuxfs**, **binfmt_misc**, etc.

Comment: see `man 5 filesystems` and `man 5 proc`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , i have found some of the information indeed in man pages. (you could have added this as answer :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodev isn't a filesystem.  It's a qualifier on the filesystems - specifically, it means the filesystem listed in field two doesn't have a device associated with it.  Yeah, there's a lot of those - over 75% of them on a typical modern Linux.

In addition to the man pages DopeGhoti pointed out, there are also manpages for a number of the specific filesystems in section 5, including ext4, sysfs, and tmpfs.  Beyond that, there's generally fairly copious amount of documentation about them in the Documentation directory of the linux kernel source.  (It's not *quite* as scary as the linux kernel source code.  It's all technically in English, rather than in C with frequent helpful comment blocks like the kernel source.)

Comment: Thank you Ed Grimm for your answer, when you say documentation directory of Linux kernel source, are you talking about the git ?

Comment: Last time I looked at the contents of the Documentation directory, it was the complement of the source.  The source files were abstruse C code with helpful comment blocks in English; the docs were abstruse English with helpful comment blocks in C. (: